# React Native accessibility identifiers only on active scene

Tags: android, react-native, accessibility

TalkBack is able to detect accessibility identifiers in my React Native 0.35.0 android app from non-active scenes I previously navigated through.  How do I prevent this so only the current scene is used when identifying accessibility identifiers?

For example I have the first page of my app render a ListView of items.  These work as expected with accessibility identifiers where any item can be selected.

[image: Image 1]

The problem is when navigate to the next page, a page that only has one line of text, all the ListView items from the previous scene are still accessible when viewing the new scene!

[image]

I am using NavigationExperimental, specifically NavigationCardStack, for navigation.  I'm aware [NavigationCardStack](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6ea26c01de74e088c486286ffdeb03177c5b3099/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationCardStack.js#L222) will render each visited scenes in the stack but am looking to find a way so only the active scene is selectable.

So far I've tried implementing a version of NavigationExperimental that only renders the active scene.  While it solves this problem the navigation animations are ruined and navigating back through the app must re-create each scene which creates a sluggish and unacceptable experience in my opinion.

While I don't love the solution I thought setting [accessible](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html#accessible-ios-android)={false} on every component from the first page may work. Unfortunately even this still left the Text components accessible.  If it had worked I could have set accessible to NavigationExperimental's property scene.isActive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue.  In React Native there is an attribute Android can set called [importantForAccessibility](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html#importantforaccessibility-android).  It's a little more intensive than I'd prefer but I implemented my own NavigationCardStack and NavigationCard (extended React Native's version to add my own logic in render).

Essentially while iterating over each scene in [NavigationCardStack](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6ea26c01de74e088c486286ffdeb03177c5b3099/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationCardStack.js#L222) I pass a new property, `isActiveScreen` which I set to true only on the active scene by inspecting the current index.

Then in [NavigationCard](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9db8910e36d610977ac473fcc326f68ff3cb03a5/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationCard.js#L99) I leverage importantForAccessibility by adding

```
importantForAccessibility={this.props.isActiveScreen ? 'yes' : 'no-hide-descendants'}
```

In this way on android only my currently visible scene has accessibility enabled while all other scenes in the stack have no-hide-descendants set.

Comment: I have implemented accessibility feature pretty well, but not working on Android 6 on my case. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue using the [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation) library. I was able to modify the `react-navigation/src/views/CardStack/Card.js`in order to fix this which can be found here, I just modify the render method (Can't get the code to format :()

[Card.js @ Github](https://github.com/awseeley/react-navigation/blob/master/src/views/CardStack/Card.js)

The following are my modifcations to this:

```
// Fixes an issue on Android whereby talkback/voiceover will pick up elements on a child view that is not active in the stack navigator
if(this.props.scene.isActive) {
  importantForAccessibility='yes';
} else {
  importantForAccessibility='no-hide-descendants';
}

return (
  <Animated.View
    pointerEvents={pointerEvents}
    ref={this.props.onComponentRef}
    style={[styles.main, style]}
    importantForAccessibility={importantForAccessibility}
  >
    {children}
  </Animated.View>
);
```

This fix has also been forked on github & published to NPM if anyone needs it as follows:
[https://github.com/awseeley/react-navigation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-awseeley)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-awseeley